# In R cannot get function from imported python file using reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

I would like to import a python file and then use a function within the python file; but it does not work (it only work for source_python). Is it suppose to be this way?

In python file called **the_py_module.py** includes this code:

```
def f1():
  return "f one"


def f2():
  return "f two"
```

**R script**

```
# Trying to import the python file, which appear to work:
reticulate::import("the_py_module")
```

Gives this output:
Module(the_py_module)

```
# But when calling the function: 
f1()
```

I get error saying:
**Error in f1() : could not find function "f1"**

This works using source python script though.

```
reticulate::source_python("the_py_module.py")
f1()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
> library(reticulate)
> my_module <- import(the_py_module)
> my_module$f1()
[1] "f one"
```

or, using your approach

```
> my_module_2 <- reticulate::import("the_py_module")
> my_module_2$f1()
[1] "f one"
```